# Polymorphic arguments in Java and fields

Tags: java, polymorphism, field

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to answer.

Ok, so I've got this class:

```
public class Class {
protected  Integer numero=1;


public Class(){}

public void method (){
System.out.println("Class do something");}


public String function(Class Object){
String res;

res=Object.numero.toString();;

return res;}
```

And this subclass:

```
public class Subclass extends Class{
   protected Integer numero=2;

    @Override
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("Subclass do something");
    }
}
```

Both have an Integer field called "numero", but with different values. The Class class has a function which takes a Class object as an argument and returns the value of "numero" (1 for class, 2 for subclass). Also, Class has a method which outputs a String "do something Class", which I have overriden in the Subclass to output "Subclass do something".

On the main method, I instantiate both a Class object ("object") and a Subclass object ("subobjeto"). I then run the method for each, and get the appropiate output.

However, when I try to print the value of the function from the Class object using the Subclass object as an argument (which is allowed if my understanding of polymorphism is correct), it returns the value of the Class field "numero" (1), when I want it to return "2".

```
public class Exe {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class object= new Class();
        Subclass subobjeto=new Subclass();
        Class arreglo[]= new Class[2];

        arreglo[0]=object;
        arreglo[1]=subobjeto;

        for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        arreglo[i].method();
        }

        System.out.println(object.function(subobjeto)+" "+subobjeto.numero);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Class do something
Subclass do something
1 2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Thank you again.

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't apply to fields.

Comment: I see @SotiriosDelimanolis. Thank you. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in Java?

Comment: @ermyuriel You really shouldn't have a field named the same as a superclass' field. If you HAVE to, use a getter instead of accessing the field directly on the object. Override the getter in the superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields aren't treated polymorphically; only methods are.  If two classes have fields with the same name, even if one is a subclass of the other, that's two *different* fields.

The lesson here is mostly to use methods, and that it's almost always a bad idea to have two fields with the same name -- it'll only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html):

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through `super`.

[JLS 8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.
>
> In this respect, hiding of fields differs from hiding of methods (§8.4.8.3), for there is no distinction drawn between static and non-static fields in field hiding whereas a distinction is drawn between static and non-static methods in method hiding.
>
> A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name (§6.5.6.2) if it is static, or by using a field access expression that contains the keyword super (§15.11.2) or a cast to a superclass type.
>
> In this respect, hiding of fields is similar to hiding of methods.
>
> If a field declaration hides the declaration of another field, the two fields need not have the same type.

Comment: Nice reference. "cast to a superclass type" is the cause for this behavior.